# How to redirect queries in Nginx

Tags: nginx

How to redirect this in Nginx:

```
www.toutdefrance.nl/tf_main.php?thema=14&status=3
```

to this:

```
www.toutdefrance.nl/vakantie-in-frankrijk/
```

in Nginx

So far this is my config:

```
if ($host = "toutdefrance.nl") {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.toutdefrance.nl$uri permanent;
}

if ($host = "toutdefrance.be") {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.toutdefrance.nl$uri permanent;
}
location = /tf_main.php {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @modx-rewrite;
}
```

Thnx
HUrby

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($host = "toutdefrance.nl") {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.toutdefrance.nl$uri permanent;
}

if ($host = "toutdefrance.be") {
  rewrite ^ $scheme://www.toutdefrance.nl$uri permanent;
}
```

Please, read this http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Server_Name - server block much better, so

```
server {
   server_name toutdefrance.nl toutdefrance.be;
   return 301 $scheme://www.toutdefrance.nl$request_uri;
}
```

and redirect:

```
location = /tf_main.php {
   set $point "$arg_thema:$arg_status";
   if ($point = "14:3") {
      return 301 /vakantie-in-frankrijk/;
   }
}
```